# How can I test pages with links without pushing changes to my live website?

Tags: html

Whenever I make changes to a page on my website, I obviously want to test them before pushing the changes to my live website. Generally I do that by opening up the file location in chrome, e.g. `file:///C:/Users/TheGuywithTheHat/Documents/website/index.html`.

The problem with that is that for a link* to work on my site, it needs to be `http://www.foo.com/foo`, `/whatever`, or similar. When testing locally, `http://www.foo.com/foo` links to the website, and `/foo` links to `file:///C:/foo`.

The only way I can see to test changes locally is to temporarily replace all occurrences of `http://www.foo.com/` with `file:///C:/Users/TheGuywithTheHat/Documents/website/`, and not use relative links at all. Once my site grows to dozens of files, most with links in them, this will be terribly inefficient.

Is there a better way to test changes without putting them on my live website?

If it makes any difference, I'm using Windows 7, and the site is hosted by my Raspberry Pi.

---

<sup>*i.e. `<a href="whatever">` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whatever.css" />`</sup>

Comment: you can use [wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install a webserver on your local machine and test your website on the server. This is as good as it gets. If you are using windows, check if IIS is available for your version of windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subst` command in Windows to make a virtual drive out of a folder. I'm assuming you don't want to install XAMPP or similar. Also assuming you're using Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am using windows.

Comment: If you need to know how to use this command there is documentation here https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true

However it's pretty straightforward

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat just wondering if you ended up finding this answer useful

Comment: Just tested it out—it appears to work great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're got a live website hosted on a Raspberry Pi?! Pretty impressive.

I've got no idea how the `subst` command helps you, and it would be interesting to find out exactly how it does. But, for future reference, this is how everyone else does it.

First option: take your site offline, but make sure that you (and only you) can still see it from your own IP address. Do the changes, test it as if it's a live website, put it back online when you're happy with it. I wouldn't normally suggest this, but it seems that you already take your site offline anyway. To do this, Apache on your Pi must have `mod_rewrite`, and you need a `.htaccess` file at the top level of your site, containing something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 503 /sitedown.html
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100.101.012.103
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitedown.html$                      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitedown.html [R=503]
```

where `100.101.102.103` is the IP address your ISP has given you (I'm assuming you've got one). Add a `sitedown.html` to the top level of your site, with a message saying something like 'Site maintenance; come back later', or whatever. To make your site go live, comment out these lines (add a `#` in front of them). To make it visible only from `100.101.102.103`, uncomment the lines, as above. You may have to add an `AllowOverride All` to the relevant directory or virtual server section in your `httpd.conf` (or `apache2.conf`, or whatever it's called on the Pi). Ask if it doesn't work.

Second option: when you do this properly, you do it with a 'staging server'. You have a copy of the website on a local (or remote) server (the staging server), and test changes there. When you're done, you copy the entire site to your production site (on unix, you'd `rsync`, or whatever). This is why the other answers have suggested wamp/xampp - they're suggesting that you create a second web server locally, on your Windows computer. You can do that, but it would make more sense to create it on the Raspberry Pi itself, or on a second Pi.

So, option 2, get a second Pi, put it on your local network. Develop the site on it, and access it from your browser via it's local IP address (something like `192.168.1.100/mysite`, or whatever). This is a bit tricky, because you have to set up your second Pi (`httpd.conf`, symlinks in `/var`, etc) slightly differently, but it's the proper way to do it.

Third option: if you can't afford a second Pi, put your staging server on the first Pi, so that it's running two sites. One of them is only visible to you (via the rewrites above), the other one is public. You need to set up for two virtual servers, or just two directories, in `httpd.conf`. Also a bit tricky. You'll probably need to ask for details if you try it.

Comment: Actually, I'm using nginx, not apache. I would like to keep the server up as much as possible, though, so I don't think I'll go with nginx's version of the first option. What I'll probably do eventually is option 3. Thanks for the time you put into this answer!

Comment: `Subst` works sort of like symbolic links, only the purpose is to map directories to virtual drives (ex. `C:\website` => `Z:`). When a file is requested using a relative path (for example `/index.html`), that gets translated as follows: `file:///Z:/index.html` => `Z:\index.html` => `C:\website\index.html`. In a nutshell it's basically a hack to fix relative path names.